# Using a different point to set coordinate system

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching the whole internet and was successful. 
What I want is to use the point (0/0) to at a specific point. Right now, it' destination is at the top left corner.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  The best answer depends on the specifics of what you're trying to achieve.  For instance, if you're talking about GDI+ then the answer is `TranslateTransform`.  If you're talking about where to position controls, the answer is you can't, so you would just have perform the appropriate arithmetic every time. Basically, don't be so vague.  ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Yes, translateTransform seems to be the thing I'm looking for. I am using GDI+.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and keep those in mind when posting future questions.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    dim p as point = new point(0,0)
```